# Making a HDMI switch basic question

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, hdmi

I am doing a hobby project and I found a place to get PCB HDMI jacks and I wanted to incorporate an HDMI switch into the board. My question, is there an IC that I can use as the "switch". It will be like a standard 5-1 switch. at the very least if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The type of chip that will be part of what you are looking for are called LVDS low voltage differential signaling. You can find receivers and transceivers and they operating at really high clock rates, so not for the faint of heart or those light in nice equipment. Google search here https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=lvds%20switch&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=f9ddc7878f6713c1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1281&bih=708

Comment: wondering why the text "Thanks so much" would be edited from my post? Are we not a civilized society with manners and such. just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/audiovideo-products/analoghdmidvi-interfaces/ad8191/products/product.html) part. It is "AD8191:  4:1 DVI/HDMI SWITCH WITH EQUALIZATION". Unfortunately they don't make more than a 4:1, so you will have to cascade them. More choices [here](http://www.analog.com/en/audiovideo-products/analoghdmidvi-interfaces/products/index.html#HDMI/DVI_Switches).

However, I fear if you couldn't find these parts, you might be in over your head. As kenny pointed out, this isn't easy due to the data rates and edge speeds. Signal integrity and controlled-impedance PCB issues aren't something I would wish to deal with on a hobby project.

Comment: differential signal routing required as well don't forget :)

Comment: For personal use, there's always the possibility that a given pairing of equipment will function with something in the middle that falls far short of the spec requirements.  If the parts aren't too expensive giving it your best shot (trying to keep traces short and comparable) and seeing what happens could be worth trying.